# knockout set element data

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

***Update***
I realize this is not "the knockout way" but.

---

I'd like to update the data on an bound element directly.

To get the element's data I would use

```
var data = ko.dataFor(this);
```

I would like to do something like

```
ko.setData(element, key, value)
```

to set the elements internal data, without triggering any bindings.

I am currently doing the following.

```
       var data = {new_data:"yes please"};
       ko.cleanNode(element);
       ko.applyBindings(data, element);
```

I realize this is not best practice but I'd like to find a cleanish manageable way to do it anyhow.

After viewing the source. Is it possible to get at the setter for the datastore?

set: function (node, key, value)
https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/utils.domData.js
line 24;

Comment: *"I'd like to update the data on an bound element directly."* - I think you need to explain that first. This sounds a bit like you have a basic concept wrong.

Comment: This looks like an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me. What are you actually trying to achieve? Fighting Knockout like this is not "not best practice", it's a recipe for a bag of hurt, very likely to cause ugly bugs that are a pain to debug, and probably easily avoidable by going at it in a different direction.

Comment: Well, I feel that the foreach binding does too much work when a small change is made to one of the underlying array's item properties. Also I don't want to use an observable for each property. I have mechanisms that tell me what has changed and where. Reflecting that I want to do some crafty updates  to the html within the bound (li) element, If I don't trigger a change in the observableArray the bound data becomes stale. Call it a personal optimization strategy. In short I know the underlying model has changed but I don't want to rebuild the whole list.

Comment: It does sound like you're fighting knockout - if each property was an `observable`, when one changes it would just change that element, without changing the whole list

Comment: an observable manages subscriptions that tells any relevant binding to update. I want to say - "hey you mr binding update!", and not have to depend on using observables - which in my opinion are an anti pattern for what I am doing.

Comment: Then *explain* what you are doing. Using observables is hardly an antipattern when you build a knockout app anyway.

Comment: I've just explained. Are we not allowed to break stuff anymore?

Comment: @beedeejay You are of course allowed to do whatever you want. But if you ask for help from others, you are not setting the rules. ;) You are not supposed to make changes to parts of the DOM that are controlled by knockout, and I really have a hard time imagining why that would be a good idea. If you could make your case in a jsFiddle, I'm going to try and wrap my head around your point of view and give sound advise.

Comment: FYI, knockout only changes DOM elements when the observable they are bound to changes. So unless *you* throw away and rebuild the entire list in the view model, knockout won't throw away and rebuild the entire list in the view. Key to successful partial page updates (and therefore optimum rendering performance) is to make partial updates in the viewmodel. For example, the mapping plugin does that [when you supply a `key` function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#advanced-usage).

Comment: @Tomalak thanks - I've sussed it for now.

Comment: It seems like I'm agitating, but I'd really like to help. Either you are doing something wrong, then I get to improve your approach, or I am not aware of a situation where what you want makes sense, then I get to learn something new. Both outcomes are useful.

Answer (score 0):

`ko.contextFor(element).$data` is pretty much the same as `ko.dataFor(element)` though.

So you can just do ko.dataFor(element).relevantProperty('newValue').

Answer (score -1):

As many of the comments state - this approach is not recommended.

I scratched my itch using.

```
ko.contextFor(element);
```

which gave me access to the following.

```
$data: Object
$index: d()
$parent: Object
$parentContext: a.N
$parents: Array[1]
$rawData: Object
$root: Object
ko: Object
```

I then changed the relevent properties in the $data object.